# Using custom click events to build a funnel using sequence segments

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

Thanks in advance. I have a somewhat idiosyncratic conversion funnel I'm trying to build tracking for. Pageviews won't do because the middle steps are 1 pageview, so I want to trigger click events and build sequence segments as suggested below.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this data funnel without upgrading to 360 for custom funnels?

[image]

Comment: No, There's no other convenient way to build event-based custom funnels than using sequence segments. Another approach might be sending specifically formatted/named events that correspond to funnel progress, like `{eventAction: "hit SKU page > clicked Form 1"}` but that night require tedious coding for custom tracking.
Also, consider building this report within Data Studio. That would allow you to have a nice fixed format with all the segments and calculation included and automated data refresh.

Comment: @ДмитроБулах thanks for the reply. Are sequence segments reliable in your opinion?

Comment: yes, why not? you'll have to calculate drop-off rate by yourself but overall sequence segments work fine